# Fatal error during creation of an action with zftool

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to create an action for one controller on zendframework 1.12.x in the cmd.
When I try to create the action, this error appears for me:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setMethod() on boolean in
>   C:\Program
>   Files\ZendFramework-latest\library\Zend\Tool\Project\Context\Zf\ActionMethod.php
>   on line 198.

This is the code of the function mentioned:

```
public static function createActionMethod($controllerPath, $actionName, $body = '        // action body') {
   if (!file_exists($controllerPath)) {
       return false;
   }

   $controllerCodeGenFile = >Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_File::fromReflectedFileName($controllerPath, true, >true);
   $controllerCodeGenFile->getClass()->setMethod(array(
       'name' => $actionName . 'Action',
       'body' => $body
       ));

   file_put_contents($controllerPath, $controllerCodeGenFile->generate());
   return true;    }
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

There a ">" character on the 6 line of your code, while in the source it's

```
$controllerCodeGenFile = Zend_CodeGenerator_Php_File::fromReflectedFileName($controllerPath, true, true);
```

but that should result in a parse error.